# Submodule resources not rendering after gradle upgrade to 3.0.0+

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-library

I'm trying to upgrade the Gradle and Gradle plugin in Android application project. However once this upgrade is done, few of the resources from the sub-modules are not rendered.

**My old configurations (Everything works fine here)-**

- Gradle plugin - 2.3.3
- Gradle version - 3.3

**Gradle configurations after update -**

- Gradle plugin - 3.2.1
- Gradle version - 4.6

After this update resource rendering (XML drawables, and strings )is not working. I also checked that with gradle 4.1 and it is not working on Gradle 4.1 as well.

Note: - I'm using butternife libraryV8.1.1 for view binding.

Please assist.

Comment: `are not rendered.` You get any errors or something? Please add more helpful details.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors or warnings. However drawables from sub module are not getting displayed

Comment: It doesn't rendered-displaying in the Android Studio preview you meant? Or after compiling?

Comment: @Mohsen, The resources are not displaying in the application. I'm not facing issues in the compiling.